# How to show ng-model values in select2 text box

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ngmodel

I am using select 2 with angular 1.5.6, I’m getting values from http and assigning them to my ng-model. value is highlighted in dropdown but it not displaying in text box.

Comment: Believe there is an angular module that wraps select2. Look for that and read docs then report any further issues

Comment: I couldn't get any angular module, I think select 2 is not so compatible with  angular js

Comment: Wasn't hard to find : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/